# Set function value based on variable

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I need to assign the variable Freight_class to the value: Bigheavy, Largebox or Littlebox. For that I have to use the value of Freight. If the value of Freight is greater than 225, Freight_class must be set to Bigheavy. If Freight is greater than 99, Freight_class must be equal to Largebox. Under 99, Freight_class must be Littlebox.

Say Freight=40, then Freight_class should be Littlebox. But I can not get it to work. What do I do wrong

```
<?php
$Freight=40;

function Freight_class($Freight) {
if ($Freight > '225') {
    return ('Bigheavy');
} elseif ($Freight > '99') {
    return ('Largebox');
} else {
    return ('Littlebox');
}
}

echo $Freight_class;
```

Comment: Are `'225'` and `'99'` really strings? Where is `$Freight_class` defined? You most likely want something like `echo Freight_class($Freight);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually call your function. And `$Freight_class` is not defined anywhere.

```
<?php
$Freight=40;

function Freight_class($Freight) {
  if ($Freight > 225) {
    return ('Bigheavy');
  } elseif ($Freight > 99) {
    return ('Largebox');
  } else {
    return ('Littlebox');
  }
}

$Freight_class = Freight_class($Freight); // assign the result of your function to $Freight_class 
echo $Freight_class;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$Freight=40;

function Freight_class($Freight) {
if ($Freight > 225) {
    return ('Bigheavy');
} elseif ($Freight > 99) {
    return ('Largebox');
} else {
    return ('Littlebox');
}
}

echo Freight_class($Freight);
```

This way it would work. You have some logical errors in your code. First, it seems like youre confused with the `terms` class and `function` it looks like you tought to create a class with your function `Freight_class` but later your using it like a normal variable.

Next point is that you compare strings with integers which could lead to strange bugs.

Comment: I believe "Freight class" is merely a business logic expression, not an actual PHP class.

Comment: Also note that this does not have to be an `if-elseif-else` construction since you're returning from it. Those can be two independent `if`s and a "default" return at the end of the function (what would normally be in else).

Answer (score 0):

Working code with comments:

```php
<?php
    $Freight=40;

    // the fact that the parameter has the same hame as the variable 
    // does not mean that it is using the variable. The new $Freight
    // is block scoped and prevents access of the outer $Freight
    function Freight_class($Freight) {
        // while comparing number you should use numbers and not a string
        // containing a number
        if ($Freight > 225) {
            return 'Bigheavy';
        } elseif ($Freight > 99) {
            return 'Largebox';
        }

        return ('Littlebox');
    }

    // since Freight_class is a function and the inner $Freight differs
    // from the outer one, you have to call Freight_class with the outer 
    // $Freight as parameter
    echo Freight_class($Freight);
```